Connect XBox series X controller in bluetooth
Hello all and thanks you for your help.
Like said in the title, i want to connect a Xbox controller in bluetooth.
For now qu Can see it in the bluetooth menu, but if i click on it, it disappear and reappear again without connecting
It works fine when plug it in USB
I upgraded the firmware (5.15)
Modified the bluetooth/input.conf
Installed xboxdrv
And tried a bunch of other stuff from this site but none works
Thank you all for your help 
